# How can I write '\n' into a text file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a '\n' into a text file through python but it registers as a new line.

```
f=open(newpath + '/rewrite.py', 'w')
f.write('''#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n"''')
```

I tried to go around it and just avoid the '\n' but I keep getting internal server errors.

Comment: Did you close the file after writing the content there? In case you see some errors, provide full error trace.

Comment: As suggested in the answers below , `\\n` should fix your issue .  Modify your code to this , `f=open(newpath + '/rewrite.py', 'w')
f.write('''#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\\n"''')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can encode backslashes by escaping it with a backslash, `"\\n"` will actually put a `\` and then an `n` into the string, whereas `"\n"` encodes the actual newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Use a double backslash to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- Put a double backslash in a string to escape it, e.g. `"\\"` or `'''\\'''` for the triple-quotes you're using.
- The other is to put `r` in front of the quotes to make it a "raw" string literal that ignores backslashes, e.g. `r"\"` or `r'''\'''`

Wikipedia has a [nice illustration of Python raw string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Raw_strings).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f=open( './rewrite.py', 'w')
>>> f.write('''#!/usr/bin/python
... print "Content-type: text/html\\n"''')
>>> f.close()

~$ cat rewrite.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
```